# How to read the xml file from 14 hive

Tags: timer-jobs, custom, properties

I have a custom timer job by which I need to create custom properties using an xml file (which has all the custom properties). As for the xml file, I'm thinking to create a module for it.  And then let the timer job read this XML file from the 14 hive

Please anyone let me know how to read the xml file from the 14 hive

Thanks,

Comment: what you mean by module?

Answer (score 2):

If you use Module, the file accessible by the URL. You should only activate feature that is installs this module to a web. After this you can use [SPWeb.GetFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms476063.aspx) method.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple code to retrieve an xml document from the hive:

```
var path = SPUtility.GetGenericSetupPath("FileName.xml");
var text = GetContent(path);
content = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(path);
var doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(text);
```